# Power Spectral Density estimation method for a general signal

Tags: power-spectral-density

Starting form the following input parameters:

- `samples = 3372`
- `duration = 5.2404810335956297e-05`
- `normalized_bandwidth = 0.87814509868621826`

and using the following code I have generated the data values of a chirp signal:

```
sampling_frequency = samples / duration
bandwidth = normalized_bandwidth * sampling_frequency
chirp_rate = bandwidth / duration

x = np.arange(start=0, stop=samples, step=1)
times = x / sampling_frequency - duration / 2
theta = -np.pi * times * times * chirp_rate
chirp = np.cos(theta) + np.sin(theta) * 1j
```

Then using the periodogram formula I have computed the power spectral density of the entire signal:

```
chirp_values = np.fft.fft(chirp_values)
psd_periodogram = (chirp.imag * chirp.imag + chirp.real * chirp.real) / samples
```

But what I need is an estimation of the psd with only 512 samples.

Usually I use the Welch method, but in this case it doesn't work, since the chirp signal is a non stationary signal.
Indeed if you will try to compute the psd using welch in the following way, you will obtain a different form of the psd.

```
f, psd = signal.welch(
        chirp,
        window='hann',
        nperseg=512,
        noverlap=segment_overlap,
        return_onesided=False,
        detrend=False,
    )
```

Are there another method to estimate the power spectral density with the same interface of Welch which can deal with chirp signal ?

NB: obviously in my application I don't have the chirp parameters, but I just have the chirp values, so I can't generate a signal with less samples.

Comment: "I can't take a downsample of your signal": what does that mean, exactly, and why is it a problem?

Comment: A resempling with less samples than the initial signal

Comment: well, what is your chirp's bandwidth relative to your initial signal sampling rate? And what has a periodogram to do with downsampling?

Comment: Welch's method is just a special case of the periodogram. What specifically doesn't work for you that a different flavor of Periodogram would fix?

Comment: because I need a power spectral density of less point than the initial signal. For example assume I have a signal with 3000 samples and I would like to have a psd of 512 samples. With Welch this is possible, but since my signal can be very general it doesn't work. For this reason I'm looking for a different estimation algorithm

Comment: ah, ok, a bit of terminology confusion: The PSD is the property of the stochastic process (i.e., the signal); what you want is an *estimate* of that property, but evaluated at a specfic number of points. Well, if that's the case, Welch's method does in fact seem to be the right choice – pick your overlap and DFT size so that you get your desired number of points? And use a window — the classic periodogram is worse than Welch for non-periodic signals! Though I admit that "I know I have a chirp, but I still use a nonparametric spectral estimator" sounds a lot of alarm signals in my head!

Comment: So, please edit your question to include **a)** information on why Welch fails for you, and **b)** what the purpose of your 512-point PSD estimate is, as that will *enable* (not only help!) us to understand the limitations and requirements of your application and thus recommend a sensible PSD estimator.

Comment: still, why would any other periodogram but Welch's method work? This makes no sense: your PSD estimate assumes weak-sense stationarity, otherwise it could not depend on *only* one variable (frequency), **no matter** how you compute it. So, as I asked, what's the thing you want to do with your PSD estimate at the end?